# Remove gravatar from avatar link Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, avatar, gravatar

I am using function to change the default avatar, but it returns photo with a link from gravatar. What problem with Wordpress when they have to attach this link from that website? I want change totally it to my website link.

https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/c4d1fc512b3f9979ac82dafdf6761889?s=60&d=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fdomain%2Fimages%2Ficon%2Favatar.png&r=g

```
function sandyavatar ($avatar_defaults) {
    $myavatar = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/icon/avatar.png';
}
```

Can I use something like: preg_replace to change link?
Or where Wordpress code put in for editing it.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code fragment to your `functions.php` in your theme, to replace the gravatar-based avatar link with default avatars in local

```
function replace_gravatar_with_default_local_avatar() {
    return some_url_to_default_avatar_image;
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_avatar_default', 'replace_gravatar_with_default_local_avatar' );
```

And if you actually want sort of `cache` or the gravatar, you can establish a cache logic, and use the `get_avatar` hook to handle this. Here is an example of cache logic.

```
function cache_gravatar($avatar) {
    $tmp = strpos($avatar, 'http');
    $g = substr($avatar, $tmp, strpos($avatar, "'", $tmp) - $tmp);
    $tmp = strpos($g, 'avatar/') + 7;
    $f = substr($g, $tmp, strpos($g, "?", $tmp) - $tmp);
    $w = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
    $e = ABSPATH .'avatar/'. $f .'.png';
    $t = dopt('d_avatarDate')*24*60*60; 
    if ( !is_file($e) || (time() - filemtime($e)) > $t )
        copy(htmlspecialchars_decode($g), $e);
    else
        $avatar = strtr($avatar, array($g => $w.'/avatar/'.$f.'.png'));
    if ( filesize($e) < 500 ) 
        copy(get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/img/default.png', $e);
    $avatar = preg_replace("/srcset='([^']*)'/", '', $avatar);
    return $avatar;
}

add_filter('get_avatar','cache_gravatar');
```

Comment: Many thanks but I see no change. Link from Gravatar still appear.

Comment: Now I get what you mean, check my answer again